# Patterns for building multidimensional array with unique key

Tags: php, arrays

**Problem:**
Extract data from an object/array and represent this data using a multidimensional array with a unique key generated from the inner loop.

I always find myself building multidimensional arrays like this:

```
$final_array = array();
foreach ($table as $row) {
    $key = null;
    $data = array();
    foreach ($row as $col => $val) {
        /* Usually some logic goes here that does 
           some data transformation / concatenation stuff */
        if ($col=='my_unique_key_name') {
            $key = $val;
        }
        $data[$col] = $val;
    }
    if (!is_null($key) {
        if (!isset($final_array[$key]) {
            $final_array[$key] = array();
        }
        $final_array[$key][] = $data;
    }
}
```

I can't help but wonder if I'm constantly doing this out of habit, but it feels kind of verbose with all the key-checking and whatnot. Is there a native function I am not utilizing? Can this be refactored into something more simple or am I overthinking this?

Comment: could you add an example of input and output to the question .. and a reason for such a structure

Comment: That's a good question. When I think about when I'm writing loops like this, it's usually because I need to format data for an array that I plan on filtering or sorting in a specific way, and I need to structure the array in a certain way that makes looking up data easily.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you always doing that? Doesn't seem the common kind of stuff one works with on a day to day basis... Anyway, that's kinda cryptic (an example would be nice) but have you though of using an MD5 hash of the serialized dump of the array to uniquely define a key?

```
$key = md5(serialize($value));
```

Comment: Hmm.. I guess it's not a super every-day type thing. It's mostly for data transformation, for the sake of displaying the data. I want to reformat the data, then have it placed in an array so that I can filter it / sort it however I want. Does that make sense?